# Тип параметра функции

Tags: python

Вопрос по языку python.
Метод класса принимает какой-то объект по параметру.

```
def intersection(self, vp):
```

Можно ли в коде присвоить тип параметру vp?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если речь идет о статической типизации, то нет, нельзя. Максимум, что можно — это контракты, проверяемые во время выполнения, при вызове функции. Самое простое — используя `assert`. Например, как-то так:

```
def intersection(self, vp):
    assert type(vp) is tuple and \
           all(type(x) in (int, long) for x in vp), \
        "vp must be a tuple of integers"
    ...
```

Если хочется синтаксического сахара, в Python 3 есть аннотации, которые можно использовать.

```
@typecheck
def intersection(self, vp: tuple_of(int)):
    ...
```

И дальше проверять типы декоратором, например, http://code.activestate.com/recipes/572161/. В Python 2.x аннотаций нет, максимум что можно сделать, это [декоратор в духе](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/454322-type-checking-decorator/):

```
@requires("vp", tuple)
def intersection(self, vp):
    ...
```

[Или прописать контракт в docstring'е](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0316/), в духе:

```
def intersection(self, vp):
    """
    Does something.

    inv:
        type(vp) is tuple
    """
    ...
```

Если имелось в виду что-то другое — уточните, пожалуйста, вопрос, пояснив что значит — «присвоить тип.»